# How to delete all lines containing a particular string, but only when the character afterwards is a CJK character?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I need to delete all lines from a file containing a match for `read (symbol)`, where `(symbol)` is any CJK character. In matches were `read (symbol)` is immediately preceded by A-Z or a-z, however, then the line should not be deleted. E.g., here are some sample lines and results:

```
Do you like to read books? (not deleted)
Can you read 书? ( deleted)
.read 书. (deleted)
This is some thread 线. (not deleted)
```

How can I delete only those lines matching `(not A-Z or a-z)read (CJK symbol)`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you get the same error message that I did when using `grep -vP "[^A-Za-z]read [\x{2E80}-\x{9FBB}]+" file.txt`?

Comment: Yes, this also gives the error, however, the other solution appears to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how to match CJK characters, but if you match non-ASCII characters you *may* achieve the results you're looking for:

```
grep -vP "[^A-Za-z]read [\x80-\xFF]" file.txt
```

Theoretically, you should be able to do:

```
grep -vP "[^A-Za-z]read [\x{2E80}-\x{9FBB}]+" file.txt
```

However in my testing, I get error:

```
grep: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#CJK_unified_ideographs

**EDIT:**

```
LC_ALL="POSIX" sed -r '/[^A-Za-z]read [\o200-\o377]+/d' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Do you like to read books? (not deleted)
This is some thread 线. (not deleted)
```

Also see:

[How to delete all CJK text appearing immediately after a particular symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445341/how-to-delete-all-cjk-text-appearing-immediately-after-a-particular-symbol/12446299#12446299)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$0~/ read [a-zA-Z]+/' your_file
```