# How to delete all CJK text appearing immediately after a particular symbol?

Tags: bash, grep

I have some text like this:

```
This is some text Z书. This is Zsome more text Z计算机.
This is yet some more Z电脑 text Z.
```

I need to delete all cases matching the pattern `Z+(CJK)`, where `(CJK)` is any number of continuous CJK characters. The file above would become:

```
This is some text . This is Zsome more text .
This is yet some more  text Z.
```

How can I delete all CJK text matching this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `GNU sed` to check the codes of non-ASCII characters:

```
sed -n l0 file.txt
```

Results:

```
This is some text Z\344\271\246. This is Zsome more text Z\350\256\241\347\256\227\346\234\272.$
This is yet some more Z\347\224\265\350\204\221 text Z.$
```

---

Then you can use `GNU sed` to do the replacement you desire. In my testing I had to set my locale to POSIX:

```
LC_ALL="POSIX" sed -r 's/Z[\o200-\o377]+//g' file.txt
```

Results:

```
This is some text . This is Zsome more text .
This is yet some more  text Z.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a Perl one-liner?

```
perl -CSD -pe 's/Z\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}+//g;' inputfile
```

Comment: @Ken It should now, the switch to make Perl process Unicode was missing.

Comment: It still doesn't. Is it specific to a version of Perl? I'm using Perl 5.22.

Comment: Hm, what's actually happening on your end?

Comment: File `test` contains `なぜ私はこれを作ったのですか`: `perl -CSD -pe 's/Z\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}+//g;' test` outputs `なぜ私はこれを作ったのですか`. https://pastebin.com/hUaFLwnk might be a bit more clear.

Comment: The OP requires that there is a letter `Z` in front of the characters he wants to remove. The regex reflects that requirement. There is no `Z` in your test string, so the regex can't match. Also the `InCJK_Unified_Ideographs` Unicode category does not contain Kana, pick a different category if you to include them as well.